# Android logcat shows error

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat, android-logcat

I get this error whenever i try to run the code on my device, please tell me where am i going wrong:

```
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3182)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.speakWords(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:239)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:207)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:123)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
07-08 19:32:46.159: E/AndroidRuntime(21554):    ... 11 more
```

And the code is

```
package com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity {
public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";


public static final String lang = "eng";

private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

protected Button _button;
// protected ImageView _image;
protected EditText _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;
private TextToSpeech myTTS;

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);


    // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    // This area needs work and optimization
    if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
        try {

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
            //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                    + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            //gin.close();
            out.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
    _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

// Simple android photo capture:
// http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

protected void startCameraActivity() {
    File file = new File(_path);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

    if (resultCode == -1) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken() {
    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

        if (rotate != 0) {

            // Getting width & height of the given image.
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
        }

        // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
    }

    // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();
    speakWords(recognizedText);
    // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
    // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
    // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

    Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

    if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
        recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
    }

    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

    if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
        _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
        _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());




    }




    // Cycle done.

}

private void speakWords(String speech) {

    //speak straight away
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}


}
```

Comment: myTTS is null because you don't initialize it.

Comment: can you please suggest me a piece of code to initialize it? i am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following line

```
myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

You are using myTTS without initializing it. Before calling any member method of any object you need to initialize it first

To know the details about TextToSpeech api see the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why initialize the Activity so late ? shouldn't the following lines be just the first 2 lines of your oncreate ?

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Its not like you are updating `savedInstanceState` or the layout file ?

Comment: This isn't the problem at all. `setContentView` can be called anywhere you want as long as you don't try to initialize any `View`s inside the `layout` first.

Comment: Somewhere handleSendResult is being called, I guess the activity just returned some value before even showing the UI. So I am guessing. Lets wait a while get some more comments. I'll delete the answer else.. No worries.